# Typescript let used outside of block-scope causing ReferenceError in apps

Tags: typescript, var, lint, let

We have multiple web apps already in production working properly. During recent updates (which includes tree shaking i think), our apps crashes with the **ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variable' before initialization.**

We found some typescript source code that uses the 'let' declaration inside a block scope, and then accessing that variable outside of the block. This used to work before (not my code, but i know it is wrong).

example:

```
    let batman: number = 1;
    switch(batman)
    {
        case 0:
            let superman: boolean = false;
            break;

        case 1:
            superman = true;
            break;
    }
```

**Before:** No errors. 
**Now: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'superman' before initialization**

**Question:**
How can I automate or catch all instances of this issue without manually going through all code?

Comment: Does this transpile? I mean, don't the TS transpiler complain about this?

Comment: Yes it transpiles without errors or warnings. We're using webpack by the way. The only time the app complains is during runtime

Comment: You’ll probably want to set up https://www.npmjs.com/package/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin in your webpack config so you get compile time checks. One of the main points of using a static type checker is for compile time analysis to avoid runtime errors. You can also set up npm tasks and use ide integrations to get immediate feedback on typescript errors.